# please help rewrite url page wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created a page in wordpress

```
www.xxxxx.com/asin/
```

and I have made ​​a template with the name asin.php

url into

`www.xxxxx.com/asin/?q=B0081HBX2I`

be

`www.xxxxx.com/asin/q/B0081HBX2I`

Already tried htaccess

```
RewriteBase /asin/
RewirteRule ^asin/q/([0-9]+)$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

any help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteRule ^asin/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ asin.php?q=$1
```

Comment: thanks for the help

I've tried it but go to 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /asin/
RewirteRule ^asin/q/([0-9]+)$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

You've spelled RewriteRule wrong in the second line. Also, in your regular expression, you're only checking for numbers, try:

```
RewriteBase /asin/
RewriteRule ^asin/q/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the help

I've tried it but go to 404 page not found

Comment: You did leave your `RewriteBase /asin/` line in when you tried it right? I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RewriteBase` then your `RewriteRule` starts matching URL after `/asin/` part from start. Also you see to be using alphanum in your URL but your regex is using `[0-9]` only.

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /asin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^q/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ ?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for the help

I've tried it but go to 404 page not found